# Blueimp Fileupload add custom data to uploaded file and reset data.files array

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a dropdown on my page which looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control navbar-right" id="my_ddown">
   <option value="0">Value 0</option>
   <option value="1">Value 1</option>   
</select>
```

and I need to dynamically pass extra data to my backend when the file is uploaded. I do it with the following feature:

```
formData: {
  my_id: $('#my_ddown').val()
}
```

but I need to reinitialize fileuploader every time my select dropdown changes. Is there a better way to do this without reinitialization?

Moreover every time I reinitialize fileuploader and try to add a new file, my

```
data.files
```

array remembers previously added files and adds them into queue too, but I dont want that. I want only 1 file, lastly added. Any way to achieve this? My Blueimp file uploader code is as follows:

```
function fileupload(){ // this function is called every time drop down selection changes
        $('#files').empty();//empty the div but not files queue
        uploadButton = $('<button/>')
            .addClass('btn btn-primary')
            .prop('disabled', false)
            .text('Upload')
            .on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this
                    .off('click')
                    .text('Abort')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.remove();
                        data.abort();
                    });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: false,
            maxFileSize: 26999000,
            formData: { //additional data passed to backend
                my_id: $('#my_ddown').val()
            }
        }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
            data.files = data.files.slice(0,1);//trying to remove all previously added files from queue but it does not work
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                var node = $('<p/>')
                    .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
                if (!index) {
                    node
                        .append('<br>')
                        .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
                }
                node.appendTo(data.context);
            });
        }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
            var index = data.index,
                file = data.files[index],
                node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
            if (file.preview) {
                node
                    .prepend('<br>')
                    .prepend(file.preview);
            }
            if (file.error) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
            }
            if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
                data.context.find('button')
                    .text('Upload')
                    .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
            }
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                if (file.url) {
                    var link = $('<a>')
                        .attr('target', '_blank')
                        .prop('href', file.url);
                    $(data.context.children()[index])
                        .wrap(link);
                } else if (file.error) {
                    var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                    $(data.context.children()[index])
                        .append('<br>')
                        .append(error);
                }
            });
        }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            });
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput).parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix the issues would be welcome. Thank you

**UPD1**

As far as I found out, the problem is that event fileuploadadd is called so many times, so many items is there is data.files array. This is caused by the fact that I reinitialize fileupload plugin on every dropdown change. But if I dont do that, I am unable to send the updated data depending on the value of the dropdown at the current time. So the question is how to send the updated data depending on the current value of the dropdown. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with the following code:

```
.bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
            var input = $('#input');
            data.formData = {example: $('#my_ddown').val()};
            if (!data.formData.my_id) {
                data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
                input.focus();
                return false;
            }
        })
```